# Delphi Firemonkey TVideoCaptureDevice Live Stream From Client-Server-Client

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tcpclient, indy, tcpserver

I have been struggling to send/receive TVideoCaptureDevice Live Stream to Client-Server-Client. I am using TIdTCPServer and TIdTCPClient. When try to receive I am getting Connection closed Gracefully. How to overcome the Connection closed gracefully?
Below is my code:

## Server

//for send

```
procedure TWebSocket.videoSendServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  fip: string;
  ms: TMemoryStream;
  cmd: string;
begin
  cmd := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn(IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
  if AContext.Connection.Connected then
  begin
    fip := cmd;//AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP;
    fip := Copy(fip, Pos(':', fip) + 1, Length(fip));
    ms := vWebcamCollection.GetItem(vWebcamCollection.GetIndexByIP(fip)).StartedStream;
    ms.Position := 0;
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.LargeStream := True;
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(ms);
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('DONE', IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
  end;
end;
```

//for receive

```
procedure TWebSocket.videoReceiveServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  ms: TMemoryStream;
  cmd, viewip: string;
begin
  cmd := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn;
  viewip := cmd;
  viewip := Copy(viewip, Pos(':', viewip) + 1, Length(viewip));
  ms := vWebcamCollection.GetItem(vWebcamCollection.GetIndexByIP(viewip)).StartedStream;
  ms.Position := 0;
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.LargeStream := True;
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(ms, 0, True);
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('DONE', IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
end;
```

## Client

both timers interval is 500
//for sending stream in TTimer.OnTimer

```
procedure TfrmVideoForm.sendTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  sendTimer.Enabled := False;
  TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread, (
    procedure
    var
      aIp: String;
      ms: TMemoryStream;
    begin
      aIp := getLocalIPAddress;
      aIp := Format('send:%s', [aIp]);
      videoClient.IOHandler.WriteLn(aIp, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
      ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
      videoClient.IOHandler.LargeStream := True;
      imgVideo.Bitmap.SaveToStream(ms);
      ms.Position := 0;
      videoClient.IOHandler.Write(ms, 0, True);
      videoClient.IOHandler.ReadLn(IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
    end));
  sendTimer.Enabled := True;
end;
```

//for receiving stream - fIPAddress = which IPAddress Start TVideoCaptureDevice

```
procedure TfrmVideoForm.receiveTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  receiveTimer.Enabled := False;
  TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread, (
    procedure
    var
      strm: TMemoryStream;
    begin
      videoRcvClient.IOHandler.WriteLn('receive:' + fIPAddress,
        IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
      strm := TMemoryStream.Create;
      videoRcvClient.IOHandler.LargeStream := True;
      videoRcvClient.IOHandler.ReadStream(strm);
      videoRcvClient.IOHandler.ReadLn(IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
      strm.Position := 0;
      imgVideo.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(strm);
      strm.Free;
    end));
  receiveTimer.Enabled := True;
end;
```

## code for server holding IPAdress

```
  { TWebcamItem }

  TWebcamItem = class(TCollectionItem)
  private
    fStartedIP: string;
    fStartedStream: TMemoryStream;
  public
    procedure Assign(Source: TPersistent); override;
    constructor Create(ACollection: TCollection); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property StartedIP: string read fStartedIP write fStartedIP;
    property StartedStream: TMemoryStream read fStartedStream write fStartedStream;
    procedure CreateStream;
    procedure FreeStream;
  end;

  { TWebcamCollection }

  TWebcamCollection = class(TCollection)
  private
    function GetItem(Index: integer): TWebcamItem;
    procedure SetItem(Index: integer; AValue: TWebcamItem);
  public
    constructor Create;
    function Add: TWebcamItem;
    property Items[Index: integer]: TWebcamItem read GetItem write SetItem; default;
    function GetIndexByIP(AIP: string): integer;
  end;
```

Comment: No need to do "AContext.Connection.Connected" inside "videoSendServerExecute". It is already being done by TidTCPServer.

Comment: Why is the client using `TThread.Synchronize()` in `TTimer`? If the TTimer is running in the main thread then the `Synchronize()` is useless. You should be handling your socket I/O outside of the main thread.

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you use `LargeStream=False` instead? Are you ever sending bitmaps > 2GB at a time? When `LargeStream=True`, `TIdIOHandler.Write(TStream)` sends the stream size using an `Int64`, otherwise it uses an `Integer` instead. The way Indy handles host<->network byte swapping for 64-bit integers on non-Windows platforms looks suspicious wrong to me, so it may or may not be encoding/decoding the `Int64` values incorrectly. I'm a Windows developer, so I never had a problem with this, but lately there have been reports of `LargeStream=True` not working on Android.

Comment: I have checked in a fix now.